# Why isn't Playframework custom validation message not displayed in template

Tags: java, validation, groovy, playframework

I am trying to perform some custom validation with play framework but I don't seem to be able to get the error from the template.

The controller code is :

```
        User user = User.findByEmail(email);

        if(user != null) {
            Logger.warn("User account already created for email %s", email);
            validation.addError("email", "This email address already in use.");
            params.flash();
            flash.error("Please correct the error below!");
            signup();
        }
```

and the signup.html template:

```
#{error 'email' /}
```

I can see that the controller sees the duplicate email but the error message does not appear in the template.

Is the code above correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are going to a different view (i.e. you are redirecting back to the signup view), Play performs a redirect, which means that the errors are no longer in scope, as the signup view is treated as a new request.

To get around this, you need to keep the validation messages available for the next request, which is achieved by using the `validation.keep()` function.

So, change your code, so that just before you call `signup()`, you call `validation.keep()`.

Your code should look like

```
if(user != null) {
    Logger.warn("User account already created for email %s", email);
    validation.addError("email", "This email address already in use.");
    params.flash();
    flash.error("Please correct the error below!");
    validation.keep();
    signup();
}
```

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. Is this a Play redirect or a browser redirect?

Comment: To keep things stateless, Play calls new actions by envoking a browser redirect.